How can start act as a pointer to a node without initializing any node in the following structure declaration?

struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
} *start;

How can start act as a pointer to a node without explicitly initializing any node in the following structure declaration?
I don't understand how start can be used as a pointer to a node when there is no explicit initialization of a node. Can you explain this concept in detail?
Can someone explains me this way of writing code where *start is writtern after }.

You are right that start must be initialized before it is used. Derefrencing it with *start without initialization is UB (Undefined Behavior).

start is a pointer. But it's not initialized meaning that it is undefined behavior to dereference it. You need to assign a value to it (e.g. start = new node {};).

okay, so start is declared , how it is related to node type. and can we use start only inside the objects of node type.
can you explain in detail?

@VeerPratap start is simply an uninitialized node*. Compare with int* x; where x is an uninitialized int*.

is it something like, if we create an object of node type, the start is going to be the pointer to that object. but what if we create multiple objects?

@TedLyngmo so its like we are creating a struct , and declaring a node* i.e. *start(pointer to node type).
it is basically like struct node *next;

@VeerPratap start can be assigned to point at a node (or nuilptr). If you need more pointers, you have to create them. Again, compare with int* x; - x can point at one int at a time.

can you give some code for start , how it can point to a node object or node?to explain it

@VeerPratap node foo; start = &foo; makes start point at foo.

It is exactly the same as struct node { int info; struct node *next; }; struct node *start;. Many C programmers believe shorter code is better.

@VeerPratap Where are you learning C++ from btw? Is it a book or some online resource?

i.e. start can reference to any one node ?

https://www.sanfoundry.com/

learning dsa, wanted to expertise it , giving my all

@VeerPratap start is just a regular node* variable. If you're wondering about pointers, get a good C++ book. (The "C nature" of that code suggests that learning C++ from where you found it is a waste.)

Dupe: Variable name after struct definition and even better Defining structure variable after structure type

@VeerPratap sanfoundry seems to be a set of tests - but what resource(s) are you using to learn the language?

i have gone through the freecodecamp beginner to advanced c++ course, now moving ahead to DSA.

@VeerPratap "i have gone through the freecodecamp beginner to advanced c++ course..." I  would instead recommed a good c++ book

@VeerPratap If those courses are any good, this should have been covered somewhere. You certainly can not have learned advanced C++ without understanding this.

there were enough pointer lesson, though pointer realted to classes or structs were not covered.which made me a bit confuse.

can you suggest some resource?

@TedLyngmo can you suggest some good resources or book where i can further practice and maybe some book that helps me building good advance projects

@VeerPratap user12002570 gave a link to a list of good C++ books above.


Can someone explains me this way of writing code where *start is writtern after }.

Basically, you defined the type node in the declaration statement of variable start. It's doing 2 things in a single statement.
An alternative is to define the struct node in a separate statement and then use the node to declare other variables such as start:
struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
};

node *start = new node {};

